# How to display overlay when React Native Map Marker On Pressing

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, react-native-maps

I want to display overlay component when pressing the map marker. When pressing the button, overlay is showing fine. But when pressing the marker, it is not showing. Can someone let me know about how to display overlay when pressing the map marker.

Here is the code.

```
const toggleOverlay = () => {
  setVisible(!visible);
};

return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
  
  <MapView style={styles.map}
    showsUserLocation={true}
    followUserLocation={true}
    zoomEnabled={true}
    showsMyLocationButton={true}
    initialRegion={ mapRegion}  
    provider = {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
    showsTraffic={true}
    >   
  
        {
        locationPoints? locationPoints.map((point) => (
              <Marker
                coordinate={{
                  longitude: parseFloat(point.PointLongitude),
                  latitude: parseFloat(point.PointLatitude)                
                }}
                title= {point.name}
                pinColor={'blue'}
                **onPress={() => (toggleOverlay)}**
              >                
              </Marker>               
            ))
      : null}  
       
  </MapView>

 <Button title="Confirm Address"   
 **onPress={toggleOverlay}** />

<Overlay isVisible={visible} onBackdropPress={toggleOverlay}>
<Text>Your Address</Text>
<View>
<Text>Address</Text>
</View> 
</Overlay>

</View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**try, maybe it works)**

```
{
locationPoints? locationPoints.map((point) => (
    <Marker
        coordinate={{
            longitude: parseFloat(point.PointLongitude),
            latitude: parseFloat(point.PointLatitude)
        }}
        title= {point.name}
        pinColor={'blue'}
            onPress={toggleOverlay}
       />             
    ))
 : null
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I have tried this and it is not working.